# Pandas/MLP :: plot 36 months instead of 12 only on 3 year period

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Below code snippet shows show revenue growth/decline of 3 companies for 3 year period however in this format I'm not able to find out how to add following:

1) instead of either seeing only 12 months out of 3 years (df.PublishedAtUtc.dt.month) or seeing very rugged graph based on year(df.PublishedAtUtc.dt.year), how do I see 36 or any amount month period(I tried different parameters with no luck)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NzjJ.png

```
sums = df.groupby(['Company Name', df.Datetime.dt.month])['PaidTotal'].sum().reset_index(level=0)
for company in sums['Company Name'].unique():
sums[sums['Company Name'] == company]['PaidTotal'].plot();
```

Data sample only - original has thousands of lines:

```
Company Name    PaidTotal   Datetime
585 CompanyA    218916.0    2016-10-14 10:51:07
586 CompanyB    430000.0    2016-01-23 11:05:08
591 CompanyB    546217.0    2016-09-26 14:20:00
592 CompanyC    73780.0     2016-12-07 07:52:01
593 CompanyA    132720.0    2017-10-04 16:14:10
595 CompanyC    52065.0     2017-11-12 14:32:40
585 CompanyA    234566.0    2017-10-14 10:51:07
586 CompanyB    252325.0    2017-01-23 11:05:08
591 CompanyB    546217.0    2018-09-26 14:20:00
592 CompanyC    745780.0    2018-12-07 07:52:01
593 CompanyA    1322320.0   2018-10-04 16:14:10
595 CompanyC    5432065.0   2018-11-12 14:32:40
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be better if you limit your question to just ONE question (excuse me for truism). Questions are free you can always ask second-third-hundredth of them. Which question **matters most now** for you?

Comment: Hi Alex, apologies. First question.

Comment: I recommend you  to remove questions 2 and 3 completely. You can always ask them later as separate questions. Concentrate attention on what matters most for you **now** and you will get help faster. Find `edit` under your post, remove questions 2-3, edit your python code - there obviuos indentation error exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `Datetime` object to store your dates, so you will be able to use the Matplotlib's `plt.plot_date()` function documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to solve your problem.

This function assumes that you're storing the dates/times as Datetime objects. So, you must specify this by passing `xdate=True` (see the code below).

To plot any range of Datetime objects `datetimes` with their paid totals `totals`, use something like this:

```
plt.plot_date(dates,totals,xdate=True)
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('totals')
```

This should give you what you're looking for, something like this using your sample data: [image]